# GNU tar symlink preservation on case by case basis

Tags: tar, gnu

I'm trying to create a tarball, and there is one specific file that I need to preserve as a symlink in the tarball.  However, there are a lot of other symlinks that I can't preserve as symlinks, because they point to files outside the scope of the tarball - if I don't use the "-h" option the tarball will be useless to anybody but me.

Is there a way I can override the "-h" option for a single file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**Untested!**

1. Create the tarball (excluding all symlinks)
2. Use the `--append` flag to add the one symlink you
   want `tar -h --append --file=mytarball.tar MySymlink`

[How to Add Files to Existing Archives](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/Misc/Unix-info/tar/tar_28.html)

Comment: brilliant!  thanks, I'll test this myself when I get a chance, and accept your answer.